# Recycling flow if the chemical process of acetylene and hydrocyanic acid

Tags: physical-chemistry, chemical-engineering, process-chemistry

I'm having some issues trying to solve this problem, because the concentration of inert in the recycling flow that I calculated is bigger that the concentration of the inert that is enterying to the system, so I'd like to know if you can help me with it (the section b).

Acrylonitrile is produced industrially by the reaction of acetylene and hydrocyanic acid in the gas phase:

$\ce{C2H2(g) + HCN(g) -> CH2=CHCN(g)}$

Acetylene and hydrocyanic acid, both with a purity of 95% by weight, enter the system in a molar proportion of 10: 1 and 85% of the entering hydrocyanic acid is converted into the reactor, giving acrylonitrile. All the acrylonitrile of the reaction product and the unreacted gases are recirculated to the reactor.

Since the raw materials contain a gaseous inert, there is a purge so that the concentration of inert in the recirculation does not exceed 6% by weight. For a feed of 200 kg / h of fresh pure acetylene entering the system, calculate:
a) The acrylonitrile production in kg / h.
b) The recycling flow (kg / h).
c) The composition of the stream leaving the reactor.

[image: Flowchart of the chemical process]

Comment: Your process is not clear. You say that all the acetylene, HCN and acrylonitrile crossing the condenser are recycled in the reactor. How and how much acrylonitrile is separated ? And what is P ? And how is P separated form R after the condenser ?

Comment: Let's see your calculations so far.